# Context in Malsup's jquery Ajax form plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-forms-plugin

I found [Malsup's JQuery Form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) quite handy in `ajaxyfying` my forms. However I am unable to refer to the target element on which the submit event occured in success and error callbacks. The `this` keyword in the refers to the `ajaxForm` object and not the DOM element.

I have lots of small forms on my page. Like accept and reject buttons against requests and I want to submit those forms using ajax. When it gets completed I want to remove that form from DOM and display a message "Request Successful!" or so. But I am unable to locate the target which actually submitted the form.

I know I can pass a `context` option which will be the context of all callbacks, in that too I am unable to make out how to refer to the element on which the submit event occured?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it.

I can pass a `beforeSubmit` function in which I set the context to the target.

```
$('form').ajaxForm({
    beforeSubmit: function(arr, $form, options){
        options.context = $form;
    }
    //Rest of the options and callbacks
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help anyone out but this is how I got it to work:

**HTML:**

`<form action="/route/controller" method="post" class="ajaxForm" data-target="#ajaxContainer_1"></form>`

**JS:**

`$(function() {
        $('.ajaxForm').ajaxForm({
            beforeSubmit: function(arr, $form, options){
                options.target = $form.data('target');
            },
            delegation: true, 
            resetForm: true
        });
    });`